# Any optimization post assembly instructions

Tags: assembly, nvidia

Is there any optimization done by Nvidia compiler post SASS? To be more precise, if I edit the SASS code to do certain operation, can I be assured that they will exactly run on the device as it is in the SASS file or there is a chance that the compiler optimizing these instructions (that are in the SASS file) as well?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer. No this is not possible. SASS is the final version that runs on the GPU.